# how to identify the current page index while using the pagecontrol with scrolling?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am using pagecontrol with scrolling functionality.

In that page control i have created 3 labels and two button.

Now i want to perform functionality while clicking on the button.for that how can i identify

the current page while perform the ButtonClick event.

By clicking on the button i want  to show another lable which is already created butat that

time it is hidden. Please guide me.

here is the code for creating object in pagecontrol:

```
         UILabel *lblReward=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:pageFrame];
    [lblReward setFrame:CGRectMake(i * (scrollView.bounds.size.width)+60, 200, 200, 25)];
    lblReward.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    lblReward.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    [scrollView addSubview:lblReward];
    NSString *strReward=[[pageControlData objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Reward"];

    NSLog(@"strDetails=%@",strReward);
    [lblReward setText:strReward];
    [lblReward release];

       UIButton  *btnCheckButton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:pageFrame ];
    [ btnCheckButton setFrame:CGRectMake(i * (scrollView.bounds.size.width)+250, 260, 20, 20)];
    [btnCheckButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NO.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [btnCheckButton addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    [scrollView addSubview:btnCheckButton];
    [btnCheckButton release];  


    UIButton  *backButton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:pageFrame ];


    [ backButton setFrame:CGRectMake(i * (scrollView.bounds.size.width)+10, 410, 30, 30)];
    [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Arrow Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [scrollView addSubview:backButton];
    [backButton release];  


    UIButton  *showcaseButton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:pageFrame ];
    [ showcaseButton setFrame:CGRectMake(i * (scrollView.bounds.size.width)+270, 410, 30, 30)];
    [showcaseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Showcase Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [showcaseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showcaseButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [scrollView addSubview:showcaseButton];
    [showcaseButton release];  


}
```

Now i want to show the labelreward by clicking on checkButton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the scrollview's contentOffset property to determine the page. Example:

```
NSInteger index = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current page no of your page control by:-

```
int currentPageNo=[*yourPageControlObjectName*.currentPage];
```

From Apple Docs:-

```
currentPage
```

The current page, shown by the receiver as a white dot.

```
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger currentPage
```

Discussion
The property value is an integer specifying the current page shown minus one; thus a value of zero (the default) indicates the first page. A page control shows the current page as a white dot. Values outside the possible range are pinned to either 0 or numberOfPages minus 1.